# Kernel Authorization File Operation Scope broken in Mavericks

Tags: c++, macos, security, kernel, osx-mavericks

I've developed a system that requires monitoring of files with a kext, which registers with the file operation scope (KAUTH_SCOPE_FILEOP).
In OSX 10.8 and older, everything works as expected and execution of programs would provide the required pid, ppid and file name of a program that was beginning execution.

In the vnode scope, I retrieve the pid  in the callback, as recommended in the book 'Mac OS X Internals', as follows: -

```
data.pid = vfs_context_pid((vfs_context_t)arg0);
```

For the file scope I use: -

```
proc_t self = proc_self();
data.pid = proc_pid(self);
proc_rele(self);
```

The problem I'm seeing, in Mavericks, occurs when an application spawns a helper app, via xpc. For example, installing a package (.pkg) launches Apple's Installer which uses the associated 'runner' helper application.

When the filescope reports the execution of 'runner', the filepath is correct, but the pid and ppid that is reported, is that of the parent app, Installer and not that of the helper application.

When testing, registering with the VNode scope (KAUTH_SCOPE_VNODE) reports the correct pid and ppid.

As stated in Apple's documentation, the file operation scope can be used to implement an anti-virus scanning program.

In this situation, if the pid and ppid of a helper app are reported as that of its parent, the helper app could be undetected.

Can someone tell me how to retrieve the correct pid and ppid of helper applications when registered with the file operation scope in Mavericks?

Comment: Are you sure that the helper apps aren't actually executed under the same process? When I played around with KAUTH_SCOPE_FILEOP I would see a process fork itself and then execute another process (thus I would actually get two notifications). Also note that in the boot in order to get the PID that way you must be using the VNODE scope, so the question doesn't make complete sense as posed (you cant retrieve the PID that way from a KAUTH_SCOPE_FILEOP listener). Anyways, are you sure it's not just showing you forks?

Comment: @DanZimm, thanks for pointing out an issue in my question (now updated). You're right that the filescope requires a different method to retrieve the pid. Even if a fork occurs, the child process would surely have a new pid? The filescope reports the child's name with the parent's pid, where the vnode scope correctly shows a new pid.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due the fact that Apple is replacing calls to fork/exec with posix_spawn.

The nature of posix_spawn means that file scope is notified before the actual process is created, which is the reason for seeing the parent pid, rather than that of the child.

KAuth and the file scope pre-date posix spawn, which is why it isn't effective in this situation.

The solution is to use the VNode scope instead.